# Truncating Python Command-line Argument

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, argv

What is the issue truncating sys.argv? Trying to do temp = sys.argv[1, :5]

**>> stub.py 123456789**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python            
import sys
temp = sys.argv[1]
print temp
print temp[:5]
print sys.argv[1, :5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just isn't how to index regular python lists, that is a `numpy()` slicing convention.

Simply use `sys.argv[1][:5]` to get your desired result.